# R find and create an index "1" or "0"

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that contains one column named H:

```
  H    Index
  11
  11
  11
  11
  12
  12
  12
  13
  13
  14
  14
  15
  15
  15
  16
  17
  18
  19
  20
  20
  20
  21
  22
  23
  00
  00
  00
  01
  01
  02
  03
  04
  04
  04
  04
  05
  06
  07
  07
  07
  08
  09
  09
  09
  10
  11
  12
```

How can I create a new column filled with 1 for H ranged from 10 to 18 (e.q., 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and 18) and filled with 0 for H from 19 to 09 (e.q., 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 and 09)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: Read `help("%in%")` and then `help(logical)` for what the resulting underlying integer values are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could also do

```
df$Index <- +(df$H<19 & df$H>9)
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
df$Index <- ifelse(df$H < 19 & df$H >9, 1, 0)
```

---

If the 'H' column is `character`, we convert it to `numeric`

```
 df$H <- as.numeric(df$H)
```

Or if it is `factor`

```
 df$H <- as.numeric(as.character(df$H))
```

and then perform the operations mentioned above

```
 df$Index <- +(df$H < 19 & df$H >9)
```

Comment: My answer originally used ifelse, but I was told that as.integer would be better (and I agree that it is cleaner looking at least).  What does the `+( ... )` notation do?  I don't think that I have seen that before.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, I didn't check your edits.  Yes `ifelse` would be slower, but it is a canonical method.  Using `+` will coerce `TRUE/FALSE` to binary `1/0`.  It should be faster even when we compare to `as.integer` (not tested)

Comment: No problem with the _ifelse_.  I was just surprised to see a gold badge user recommend it when it was another gold badge that told me it is better not to use it.  I figured maybe there was something that I didn't know about it that would mean to avoid it.  I don't have to do this type of coercion often, but I'll have to remember that `+` notation.  It is certainly a lot less to type.

Comment: The unary `+` applied to booleans is a shorthand notation for `as.numeric()`. A double negation `!!` applied to numerical values can be considered as the opposite operator: a shorthand notation for `as.logical()`. For example, `!!(+TRUE)` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy as you need the value based on a range.  If *df* is the dataframe,

```
df$H<19 & df$H>9
```

will give you a vector of True/False testing if the value is in the range from 10 to 18 or not.  Using the *as.integer* function, you can cast this to 1s and 0s.<sup>**1**</sup>

```
df$Index <- as.integer(df$H<19 & df$H>9)
```

---

If the column is a character vector, we can first cast to a numeric value before doing the test

```
df$Index <- as.integer( as.integer(df$H)<19 & as.integer(df$H)>9)
```

If the value is not an integer, we can use *as.numeric* instead to do the inner casts.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> This works because according to `help(logical)`, *True* is coerced to 1 and *False* is coerced to 0 when called in a numerical context, and *as.integer* will follow those coercion rules.  We could have manually done this coercion as well with the *ifelse* function as `ifelse(df$H<19&df$H>9,1,0)` which examines each element in this logical vector and uses a 1 if it is true or a 0 if it is false.

Comment: How about the column H is chr ?

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang I expanded the answer to cover that.